# converting text file to gps track file

Tags: exiftool

Note:Question is edited according to suggestion

I want to geotag  my images

im1.jpg
   im2.jpg

Content of Images
[image]

---

I tried the solution  with csv but getting this error

I have a csv file `adata.csv`

```
SourceFile,DateTimeOriginal,GPSLatitude,GPSLongitude,GPSLatitudeRef,GPSLongitudeRef
im1.jpg,1635.387709,52.23829321,10.54680910,52.23829321,10.54680910
im2.jpg,1645.892446,52.23828047,10.54680857,52.23828047,10.54680857


C:\EXIF>exiftool -csv=adata.csv Images
```

Error:

```
C:\EXIF>exiftool -csv=adata.csv Images
No SourceFile 'Images/im1.jpg' in imported CSV database
(full path: 'c:/exif/images/im1.jpg')
No SourceFile 'Images/im2.jpg' in imported CSV database
(full path: 'c:/exif/images/im2.jpg')
    1 directories scanned
    0 image files read
```

Comment: Change directory to `Images` (`cd Images`) or add the rest of the path to the `SourceFile` column (full path `c:/exif/images/im1.jpg` or relative path `./images/img1.jpg`).

Comment: Also, remove the 2nd column (the DateTimeOriginal column), as you now don't have actual timestamps in it and this will return an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about the gpx format but your example doesn't include timestamps, which are required for exiftool to be able to sync between images and the track.  Another thing to watch for is the fact that the gpx timestamps are supposed to be in UTC, which may require some work to sync properly, especially if the timestamps in your text file are local time.

Instead, I'd suggest converting your TXT file to a CSV file and using the [`-csv` option](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#csv-CSVFILE).  Some simple changes would be required.  The first column would need to be changed to filenames, which it looks like would only require adding `.jpg` to each number in the first column. The column header for the first column would need to be changed to `SourceFile`. The Time column could be removed, unless you need to add the timestamps to the image files, in which case I'd suggest changing the column header to `DateTimeOriginal`.  The Latitude and Longitude column headers need to be changed to `GPSLatitude` and `GPSLongitude`.  Finally, because GPS metadata is unsigned, you will need to set the reference tags.  Duplicate the `GPSLatitude` and `GPSLongitude` columns and change the headers to `GPSLatitudeRef` and `GPSLongitudeRef`. This all should be relatively easy in a spreadsheet program such as Excel or LibreOffice.

At that point your new CSV file should look like this:

```
SourceFile,DateTimeOriginal,GPSLatitude,GPSLongitude,GPSLatitudeRef,GPSLongitudeRef
1.jpg,13:22:05,45.9874167,-76.875233,45.9874167,-76.875233
```

You could then run this command to fill the gps data
`exiftool -csv=data.csv c:\Images`